# Load controller dynamically just like model

Tags: controller

As we can load third party component model like this:

```
Loader::import('joomla.application.component.model');
JLoader::import('modelname', JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_componentname/models');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance( 'modelname', 'ComponentNameModel' );
```

Is there any similar way to load sub-controller of a third party component and execute a method in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
JLoader::import('controllername', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_componentname/controllers');
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('controllername');
$controller->execute('task');
```

Not sure what you want to do, which task you want to execute, etc. But that should work as a start.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong and haven't tested this, but try using:

```
JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.controller');
JLoader::import('modelname', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_componentname/controllers');
$controller = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('controllername');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
JLoader::register('Helpername', dirname(__FILE__) . DS . 'helpers' . DS . 'filename');
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
JLoader::import('Controllername', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_componentname/controllers');
$model = JControllerLegacy::getInstance('controller name');
$model->execute(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get("task"));
```

Comment: This is what I mentioned in my question, I can load model with your code from /components/com_componentname/models. But I am looking something to load controller, not the model. I believe its a typo in your code or you have not understood my question. Let me know.

Comment: Sorry, This is my mistake JLoader::import('Controllername', JPATH_ROOT . '/components/com_componentname/controllers');